# how to filter by key in object array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am filtering data for angular material table. When the user select a column, then I want to filter data according the key selected. How can i achieve this?

**data**

```
0: {id: "1", name: "G", progress: "58", color: "LD"}
1: {id: "2", name: "Mel", progress: "37", color: "LD"}
2: {id: "3", name: "Nos", progress: "29", color: "LD"}
3: {id: "4", name: "Zane", progress: "81", color: "LD"}
4: {id: "5", name: "Dave", progress: "98", color: "LD"}
```

**wanted data**

```
0: {name: "G", progress: "58", color: "LD"}
1: {name: "Mel", progress: "37", color: "LD"}
2: {name: "Nos", progress: "29", color: "LD"}
3: {name: "Zane", progress: "81", color: "LD"}
4: {name: "Dave", progress: "98", color: "LD"}
```

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: `const {id, ...dataFiltered} = data`  ... `.map(({id, ...data}) => data)`

Comment: `data.map(({id, ...rest}) => (rest));` 

Comment: If the key is stored in a variable and you want it to be dynamic: `const key = 'id'; const newArray = array.map(({ [key]: k, ...rest }) => rest)`